# May one engage in secular entertainment prior to the morning prayers?

Tags: halacha, shacharis-morning-prayer

Is one allowed to perform activities such as reading a secular book, or watching a secular movie before praying the morning prayer, shachrit?

I am not well-versed in the laws of morning prayers; but, from what I was able to find, there is no such prohibition in the halachic texts.

[This TorahMusings article](http://www.torahmusings.com/2013/12/before-the-shacharit-prayer) cites the following as a source that it's prohibited to write secular ideas:

> Eshel Avraham 89:3 presents a logical rationale that any ordinary or
>   temporary work permitted on chol hamo’ed is also permitted before
>   prayer. Halichot Shlomo 2, notes 8 and 16, writes that this
>   prohibition is a law based on precedence; one is forbidden to put his
>   needs before praying. However, if the time of his regular minyan has
>   not yet begun, he may be permitted to perform these activities despite
>   the fact that amud hashachar has already arrived. It seems that in
>   practice, one may be lenient regarding this when another doubt is
>   added to the equation. For instance, when there is doubt as to whether
>   his activity is an ordinary activity or a mitzvah-related activity and
>   the time of the minyan in which he regularly prays has not yet
>   arrived, it may be possible to be lenient.

Does "writing secular ideas" constitute a "greater" act than consuming secular entertainment thereby permitting it?